# Wait on thread started from another class - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have encountered a threading issue I cannot solve. I want to perform a large Core Data save operation of about 12000 objects on a separate thread in a certain class, and in another class control a button action in relation with the save operation being finished. What is the best approach on this?

This is how the save operation looks like:

```
     Class A

    -(void) saveAsync
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^
                       {
                           //arrayOfObjects holds the 12000 objects

                           for(aClass *object in arrayOfObjects)
                           {
                               [self saveToCoreData: object];
                           }

                           NSLog(@"Finished saving");

                       });
    }

    -(void) saveToCoreData : (aClass *) object
    {
        //perform save operation here
    }
```

And this is the action method on my button (which is really nothing yet)

```
    Class B

    -(IBAction) buttonActionMethod
    {
        //take different actions depending on the objects being persisted to the store or still saving
    }
```

I am asking for a solution that would allow me to know if the objects are saved at a button press. The code I provided is just a raw example to express the idea, I don't expect it to work  like that. I have thought of using NSOperationQueue or create threads or use groups, but I have not found a solution that works.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The simplest approach is probably to post a notification using `NSNotificationCenter`, or if you want to know whether the save is completed when the button is pressed, just set a boolean value when you complete the save

Comment: I can post a notification when the save is finished, but how would I control the button action through the observer method as no notification would be posted until the end of the operation and the button could be tapped before the end of the operation.

Comment: Store a boolean property in class B, which is initialised to false.  In the notification observer method in class B simply set the boolean to true.

Comment: Your solution is applicable only if -(void) saveToCoreData : (aClass *) object method is executed on the same thread that was started by my dispatch, else (such is my case) the save operations are launched themselves on other threads and the iterations are finished before the objects are actually saved.

Comment: No, because you can post the notification from the end of the loop but inside the dispatch_async, or you can call dispatch_group_async from inside the loop and use a `dispatch Group` https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW25

Comment: Yes, this solution should work fine. The funny thing is that I cannot modify the save method as it's used in tones of other places as it's a very large app, I have to create a new one that puts the saves in my group. Anyways, this was a good answer, thank you Paulw11!

Answer (score 0):

You need to store a BOOL on Class A, which will indicate the state of saving,
and check that BOOL from Class B, and make different actions.

```
 >> Class A

 @property (atomic) BOOL isSaving;

- (void)saveAsync
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^ {
        //arrayOfObjects holds the 12000 objects
        self.isSaving = YES;
        for(aClass *object in arrayOfObjects) {
            [self saveToCoreData:object];
        }
        self.isSaving = NO;
        NSLog(@"Finished saving");
    });
}

- (void)saveToCoreData:(aClass *)object
{
    //perform save operation here
}



>> Class B

- (IBAction)buttonActionMethod
{
    // take different actions depending on the objects being persisted to the store or still saving
    if (classA.isSaving) {
    } else {
    }
}
```

Comment: Please see discussion with Paulw11. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: This answer is correct - you seem to think that each invocation of `[self saveToCoreData]` is occurring on a separate thread but it isn't - you are dispatching the whole for loop on a separate thread

Comment: Although I would post a notification to advise that saving is completed rather than holding a reference to the Class A instance in Class B.

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification`:

> Posted whenever a managed object context completes a save operation.
>
> The notification object is the managed object context. The userInfo
>   dictionary contains the following keys: NSInsertedObjectsKey,
>   NSUpdatedObjectsKey, and NSDeletedObjectsKey.

I strongly recommend NOT to use any class variables, as they store class state which is not a real part of it

Comment: I do not think your solution would work taking into consideration the fact that at every object save this method is called and I have to keep track of the number of objects in the array, which I do not know in class B, and still have to store it from Class A. Maybe I misunderstood, if so, please correct me. Thank you!

Comment: @BogdanBalta in fact, it will cause to fire your method everytime when some context saves. I thought you have one-time import and you can unsubscribe after finishing of it. Anyway, you can inspect [notification object], may be it will help

Comment: @NikitaTook I strongly recommend you to start using properties, Notifications will make your code hell, and another save notifications (NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification) will also affect your screen's logic

Comment: It's really grievous that you think that `isSaving` is not a part of a class that saves data.

Comment: @l0gg3r classA may not be the class, that only persists data. It could be any class, and in that case `isSaving` is not a property. For example, `Person` class can save its own data, but what could person.isSaving means?